# Hive Getting only max occurrence of a value

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have hive table which has two cloumns,I want to get the value which occured max number of times

For example in my below table a value occured twice and c only once , here a value is dominat so I want only a value as shown in output

```
col1 col2
a a_value1
a a_value2
a c_value3
b b_value1
```

OUTPUT:

```
col1 col2
a   a_value1
b   b_value1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for what statisticians call the mode.  A pretty simple method is to use aggregation with a window function:

```
select col1, col2
from (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above query will return one value for each `col1`, even if there are ties.  If you want all the values in the event of ties, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.